# "extends" and "load" in one template (django project) , is this possible

Tags: python, html, css, django

I m trying to extend from the base template the navigation and the footer and also to load the static files ,but it doesnt show me any changes when im doing it (When i remove {% extends 'index.html' %} the css is working). I tried with include and it works but its broken - the body is under the footer etc. I tried also with {% block css %} and a lot of other things , but i dont think that is the way of fixing this one..

---

register_user.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}


<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/register/register.css' %}">
    <title>Register - Audi Our Love</title>
</head>

{% block content %}

<h1>Register User</h1>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in register_form %}
        <p>
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
                {{ field.help_text }}
            {% endif %}

            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p style="color:red;">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="register-button">Register</button>
</form>
<div>
    <p>Already have an account ? | <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please provide the `index.html` template.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.html   

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
        {% include 'snippets/index/header.html' %}
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
        <!-- Body -->
        {% block content %}
        <h1 class="">Welcome</h1>
        {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <!-- End Body -->
    
        {% include 'snippets/index/footer.html' %}
    
    </body>
    
    </html>

header snipped

    {% load static %}
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base/base.css' %}">
        <title>Main - Audi Our Love</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css"/>
    
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <p>Welcome back, {{ request.user.username }} | <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></p>
        {% else %}
            <p><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a> | <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></p>
        {% endif %}
    
        {% block nav-menu %}
    
        <nav class="navigation">
            <div class="toggle-button">
                <button>====</button>
            </div>
    
            <div class="nav-links">
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Parts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Fan Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'contacts' %}">Contacts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'account' %}">My Account</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <hr>
        {% endblock %}

footer snipped

    <hr>
            <div style="text-align: center">
                <h4>Our social media</h4>
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;margin: 0 5px">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
                </a>
    
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;margin: 0 5px">
                     <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                </a>
    
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none;margin: 0 5px">
                     <ion-icon name="logo-tiktok"></ion-icon>
                </a>
            </div>
    
    {% block scripts %}
    <script src="/static/js/toggle_button.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).